# How to insert a column at a certain position in a CSV file using AWK and dealing with quotes?

Tags: csv, awk, sed, csvkit

> msg_type,mmsi,timestamp,imo,name,ship_and_cargo_type,length,width,draught,eta_date,destination
>
> 24,510041000,2016-07-05 12:49:16 UTC,,,30,29,6,,,
>
> 5,371952000,2016-07-16 07:30:40 UTC,9687112,SPRING
>
> LEGEND,90,190,32,11.7,2016-08-08 00:00:00 UTC,"ONAHAMA,JAPAN"
>
> 5,412331087,2016-07-24 11:14:02 UTC,0,LU HUANG YUAN YU
>
> 117,30,0,0,0,,"" 5,775994600,2016-07-02 07:43:55 UTC,9318814,ELIZABETH
>
> A MCCALL,60,44,9,3.5,2016-11-16 06:05:00 UTC,GUIRIA

I'm trying to insert an empty column in this table in the penultimate field in this table. So for example the header would look like this:

> msg_type,mmsi,timestamp,imo,name,ship_and_cargo_type,length,width,draught,eta_date,,destination

I am using a AWK command, but it is not dealing correctly with quotes such as for "ONAHAMA,JAPAN".

Is there a better approach, how can I overcome this? Here is my attempt.

Thanks

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,","$11}' old_table > new_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular case can be solved with `sed`, but check out `perl`, `python` etc which have `csv` modules

```
$ sed -E 's/"[^"]+"$|[^,]*$/,&/' ip.txt
msg_type,mmsi,timestamp,imo,name,ship_and_cargo_type,length,width,draught,eta_date,,destination
24,510041000,2016-07-05 12:49:16 UTC,,,30,29,6,,,,
5,371952000,2016-07-16 07:30:40 UTC,9687112,,SPRING
LEGEND,90,190,32,11.7,2016-08-08 00:00:00 UTC,,"ONAHAMA,JAPAN"
5,412331087,2016-07-24 11:14:02 UTC,0,,LU HUANG YUAN YU
117,30,0,0,0,,"" 5,775994600,2016-07-02 07:43:55 UTC,9318814,,ELIZABETH
A MCCALL,60,44,9,3.5,2016-11-16 06:05:00 UTC,,GUIRIA
```

- `-E` use extended regular expression, some implementations uses `-r` instead
- `"[^"]+"$|[^,]*$` last field is within double quotes, else non-`,` characters
- `,&` replace with `,` and matched text

Answer (score 1):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,","$11}' OFS=',' old_table > new_table
```

- `v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^,]+'` - pattern defining field value